# android packagingOption: pick one from a specified jar

Tags: android, packaging

android packagingOption:

pickFirst: does not guarantee which one is picked.

need to pick one from a specified jar, not random. e.g.,

```
packagingOption {
   pickFirst  "foo.xml"@example.jar
}
```